# Displaying dates in the proper format according to the region set in iOS

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter app, I want to display dates in the proper format according to the region set in iOS, not the language. I do not want to translate messages. I simply want to display dates properly.

On iOS you can set the phones language, additional further supported languages and a region. In my case, these are my settings:

[image: Screenshot of iOS Settings]

In this case the locale would be `en_DE`, right?. I tried to determine the locale in my app to use it to format the dates, it always returns `en_US`, because this is the default. I've read that you need to set all supported locales in the `materialApp` beforehand. But if you really have to set every possible combination of languages and regions, this would be a humongus list.

Is there a simpler way of displaying dates in the proper format which I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I solved this by calling native iOS Code and receiving `Foundation.Locale.current.regionCode`.

The Code of AppDelegate.swift is the following:

```
let controller: FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
      
let regionCodeChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(
  name: "BUNDLE_ID/regionCode",
  binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger
)
      
regionCodeChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
  (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
  switch call.method {
    case "getRegionCode":
      result(Foundation.Locale.current.regionCode ?? "")
    default:
      result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
  }
})
```

In Flutter you'll have to create a MethodChannel:

```
static const regionCodeChannel = MethodChannel('BUNDLE_ID/regionCode');

regionCodeChannel.invokeMethod('getRegionCode').then((value) {
  print(value); // DE

  DateFormat dateFormat = new DateFormat.yMMMMd(value);
  print(dateFormat.format(DateTime.now())); // 15. Juli 2022
});
```